# Java @Inject with constructor with parameters

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I've a Job class which has 2 parameters in its constructor. I want to inject a service class inside. As far as I know, there should be a default constructor in order to inject an object with **@Inject** annotation. But my job class is called with **new** keyword somewhere I have no permission to edit. Example is below:

```
class MyJob {

    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    public MyJob(String myParam, String otherParam){
         // params are important and should be provided by caller
    }
}

class MyService {
    void doFunc() {...}
}

// code block that I cannot edit
// this function is placed into a JobRunner class
void runJobs() {
    MyJob myJob = new MyJob(param1, param2);
// rest of the code
}
```

If I create a default constructor in `MyJob` class, when it's initialized inside the `runJobs` function with parameters, Is MyService injected successfully or just stay as a null?
What is the best practice for this kind of a case? (I have no chance to change runJobs function)

Comment: "*or just stay as a null*" This one. For DI to happen, the DI container needs to instantiate it. It ain't magic. It has no way to magically intercept your ctor invocation.

Comment: "*I have no chance to change runJobs function*" Then it can't possibly work. `MyJob` will have to work without `MyService`.

Comment: If you can't change the `runJobs` method, then you'll have to instantiate the `MyService` yourself inside the constructor. With "regular" CDI you could try using `CDI.current().select(MyService.class).get()` to replace the injection. For Quarkus use `Arc.container().instance(MyService.class).get()` instead.